# Converting Array to Object so that ID always stays the same - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of strings as my data. I want to convert that array to an object so that I can render a list of textboxes. I want to avoid using the index in map() to populate the keys. I tried using UUIDv4 instead but realized that everytime I write something in one of the text boxes, the component rerenders and it stops the user from typing in the textbox because the component rerendered because the key was changed on the component which causes a rerender.

Is there any way to create an object from an array in React so that when I type in each textbox or delete or add a new textbox to the array and object, the IDs stay the same?

The reason UUID did not work is because UUID is giving me a new key everytime the page rerenders

I have an array

```
"[note 1, note 2]"
```

That I want to convert to an object and not have the id rerender everytime

```
"[{id: 981, text: "note 1"}, {id: 452, text: "note 2" }]"
```

I currently loop through the object and have textboxes displaying. I have functionality already written to add a new textbox and delete a specific textbox.

My main goal is to stop the rerenders from happening when I type something in any of the textboxes.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: I would guess that is what is interrupting your typing, not a change to the key. Even with the same key, if the value you are setting your input to has changed, React will rerender it. Consider not using a change handler, perhaps an onblur instead if you need to validate the value etc.

Comment: @pilchard thanks for your reply. Onblur seems to help with the typing aspect. It seems that the state will only update the text that I have in the textbox when I leave the textbox that I am writting. Obviously, this is how onBlur works. Is there anyway to have the state be lifted from the textbox when typing without having to click on another textbox to call the handler in the onBlur?

Comment: I have another component where I want to render a list of all of the text in all of the textboxes. Ideally would like that to happen in real time. The onBlur seems to allow to me continuously type in a textbox now which is great but now does not allow me to have my other component be aware of the real time text that is being written in my textboxes

Comment: Are you setting a `value` on your textbox? you could still have an onchange handler so long as you're not using state to set the value of the textbox itself, this way you can update state and use it elsewhere without rerendering your input. You can still set an initial value using `defaultValue={note.text}` see: [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: @pilchard my textbox had an onchange which lifts the state up to a parent and then the parent sends the newState back down to the child and each textbox has a value of state[index]

Comment: I'd recommend removing the `value` and using `defaultValue` instead as per my last comment. Which will allow you to add back the `onchange`

Comment: Thanks @pilchard

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve an array of objects as in your example, you could map the String array into an objects array.

```
let arr = ["note 1","note 2"];
let objArray = arr.map((arrEl, index) => {return {id: (Math.random()+index).toString(), text: arrEl}});
console.log(objArray);
```